# cocos2d-x 3.7 + SmartFox Porting error

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, smartfoxserver

I develope both cocos2d-x and SmartFoxServer.

I success C++ Dev.

However, a problem has occurred.
An error occurs when you porting.

SmartFoxServer Example wrote cocos2d-x 2.X

This version does not match me.
But looking at the example I made to match as much as possible. The error occurs too much.

So many undefined error;;
This is error I said

```
[armeabi] SharedLibrary : libcocos2dcpp.so
jni/boost/boost/asio/error.hpp:244: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
jni/boost/boost/asio/error.hpp:223: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
jni/boost/boost/asio/error.hpp:223: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
jni/boost/boost/asio/error.hpp:244: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
```

==================== android.mk ======================

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/libboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_59.a
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/libboost_regex-mgw48-mt-1_59.a
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/libboost_chrono-mgw48-1_59.a
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/libboost_iostreams-mgw48-mt-1_59.a
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/libboost_signals-mgw48-mt-1_59.a
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-s-1_59.a
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/libboost_system-mgw48-mt-s-1_59.a

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -frtti

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/cocos/platform
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Bitswarm
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Bitswarm/BBox
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Controllers
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Core/Sockets
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Core
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Entities/Data
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Entities/Invitation
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Entities/Managers
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Entities/Match
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Entities/Variables
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Entities
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Exceptions
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/FSM
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Logging
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Protocol/Serialization
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Requests/Buddylist
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Requests/Game
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Requests/MMO
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Requests
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Util/md5
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Util/XMLParser
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Util
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox/Core/OpenSSL\Win64\include


$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/smartfox)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp\
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp\
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp\
                   ../../Classes/LoginServer.cpp\
    ../../libs/smartfox/SmartFox.cpp\
```

--------------------skip------------

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: It's not the information I want. I want to know how to fix 'android.mk'

Comment: You haven't read any of the solutions proposed there, have you?

Comment: I looked up the answer in the given article. I could not be found. I still have to fix the error with the search. I Try to fix.. TT